# Help regarding Runtime.getRuntime().exec() command usage in Android app

Tags: android, runtime.exec

I am trying to make use of Runtime.getRuntime.exec() command to copy a
folder from one location to another on sdcard.
But it seems like it doesn't work

Below is the code snippet where I am trying to copy the contents from /
sdcard/etc/data to /sdcard/etc/temp/

**try
   {
   Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp -r /sdcard/etc/
data /sdcard/etc/temp");
   }catch (IOException e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }**

I also tried  creating a soft link as an alternative.. Event that did
not work.

**try
   {
   Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ln -s /sdcard/etc/
data /sdcard/etc/temp/data");
   }catch (IOException e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }**

Could someone please help me on this. Am I using the Runtime in the
proper way if not could you please suggest me an alternative..
Appreciate your help!

Thanks,
Nik..

Answer (score 2):

You probably still need to have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, in case you do not have that.

Your bigger problem is that `cp` is not in any sort of `PATH`. In fact, I do not see the `cp` command anywhere on the Android 2.2 emulator, though I have not done an exhaustive search.

The way a savvy programmer would solve this is [using Java](http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/CopyDir.html), since that eliminates your dependency on undocumented/unsupported command-line binaries.

Comment: Why would you possibly want the "cp" command, when "cat" can do everything you need? :-)

Comment: In my opinion using `cp` is much easier to learn than the java aspect. That and I use it for root commands. It's not in stock Android (as far as I know). Your phone must have Busybox installed (and generally be rooted).